# RGB image processing in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, rgb, channel

I am struggling to transform an image into its red, blue and green channels.

I am working in Qt C++, I already uploaded the Original picture and it displays in my widget, and I know that the RGB transformation will have a sort of for loop that changes pixel by pixel, I am just not sure what function I should use in changing these pixels in my loop.

Any advice?
This is what I currently have for the red Channel, I upload with QImage

```
 for(int i = 0; i < Red.width(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < Red.height(); j++)
        {
           QColor pixelC = Red.pixelColor(i,j);
           pixelC.setRed(255);
           pixelC.setBlue(0);
           pixelC.setGreen(0);



        }
    }

    QLabel RedPic;
    ui->RedPic->setScaledContents(true);
    ui->RedPic->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Red));
```

Comment: Please add some code examples. There no one write code for you. At least, show to community what you have tried.

Comment: You can do it concurrently (QtConcurrent::mapped) or via binary masking of a pixmap no? Unless your trying to shift your raw bits into a 5.6.5 or 10.12.10 rhb container in which case you need to understand what the data looks like and right a small inline bit of code to shift everything into place.

Answer (score 1):

so apparently working for 24+hours straight is never a good idea, after a good rest, I figured it out. If anyone else also has this problem, feel free to contact me, it's actually a quite easy solution.

Here are a few tips as to what I did, this is in my for loop:

```
QRgb* rgbpixel = reinterpret_cast<QRgb*>(scan + j*depth);
            int Red = qRed(*rgbpixel);
            *rgbpixel = QColor(Red, 0, 0).rgba();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the `QImage` class, that one is already an RGB image, with `QRgb QImage::pixel(int x, int y)` as accessor.
If you are talking about `QPixmap`, look at `QImage QPixmap::toImage()`.

You might want to use `QColor(QRgb color)` to transform `QRgb` (which stores it's data in an integer) into `QColor` (which has the channels as members).

If you need example code for something particular, just ask. If you start with a `QPixmap`, your result might be that you convert to `QImage`, convert the pixels into `QColor`, change the channels there, convert back to `QRgb`, insert into the `QImage`, convert the `QImage` to `QPixmap`.